# signature-verification-failure : In Flow-ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

Cannot build a typed interface for this module. You should annotate the exports of this module with types. Missing type
annotation at function return: [signature-verification-failure]
I got this error when I run "npm run flow"

```
    //@flow
import  { Component } from 'react'
import * as React from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component<any> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  render(): React.Node {
    return (
      <div className="App">

      </div>
    );
  }
```